# WMP crashes when trying to create a playlist

Tags: c#, wmp, wmplib

Im developing in C#, WinForms, a Windows desktop application where I use the windows media player component. I created a playlist (curPlaylist) and a WMP component called musica (in the designer, drag and dropping to the form). In my PC works perfectly (Windows 10) but when I want to run it on a Windows 7 machine it crashes. The Error I get is:

> Catastrophic failure: Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)

In this line:

> curPlaylist = musica.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("curPlaylist");

I build the solution in x86. Every other aspect of the application works fine (In my machine, everything works fine). I even have another WPM component (that doesn't use playlists) and works perfectly on the Win7 machine. So Is not a compatibility error.Im copying to the target machine all .dlls that I have in the build folder.
What Im missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25179947/9020340

Comment: @ArunPratap I had 2000 playlists as that user, but I deleted all, and restarted the PC and still getting that error.